# Java grabbing numbers only from Text File: Integer.ParseInt throws NumberFormatexception

Tags: java

I need help with an assignment that I have.
My assignment asks me to calculate test scores from a text file.

For example, my text file ("input.txt") shows this:

```
Lois Lane,         100, 98, 95, 90, 93, 88, 92
Marie Calendar,    85, 82, 88, 78, 85, 86, 90
Bob Marley,        70, 75, 72, 78, 80, 82, 76
Tom Brady,         82, 90, 88, 95, 92, 86, 87
Clark Kent,        99, 98, 100, 96, 100, 97, 95
Sandra Dee,        95, 93, 90, 100, 98, 89, 92
```

I would like to be able to calculate just the scores (by column).

I successfully read the file. However, I am having a hard time figuring out why Integer.ParseInt throws a "NumberFormatException".

This is the code I have so far.

```
public class testAvg {

public static int main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String token1 = " ";

    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*[a-z][A-Z]");

    List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        token1 = inFile.next();
        inputs.add(token1);
    }
    inFile.close();


    String[] inputsArray = inputs.toArray(new String[1]);

    int parsedArray = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputsArray.length; i++) {
        parsedArray = Integer.parseInt(inputsArray[i]);   // This line throws the exception
    }
    return parsedArray;

} 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post the content of `input.txt`.

Comment: May we see the text file please? Showing the code won't be enough

Comment: The problem is the names are part of the input.  Your results of inFile.next() are "Lois Lane" (a string with no digits, which isn't an integer, hence the error) followed by "100", "98", "95", "90", "93", "88", "92", "Marie Calendar", etc.

Comment: @billjamesdev Look at the `useDelimiter()` call. It actually doesn't work at all, so the entire text is returned by `next()`. It works if the regex is changed to `"[a-zA-Z\\s]*,\\s*"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a homework assignment, I'm not going to give you the full answer, but you should forget about `Scanner`.

Use a `BufferedReader`, and call the `readLine()` method. Split the line using `split("\\s*,\\s*")`. The returned array will have the name in `[0]` and the numbers in `[1]` ... `[7]`. Call `parseInt()` on those.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. :)

Comment: But, for the error in your code, the regex should be `"[a-zA-Z\\s]*,\\s*"`. A comma, any trailing whitespace, and any leading whitespace and/or letters.

Comment: Actually, `scanner.nextLine()` can also be used. He will still have to separate out the text part from the numbers part. BufferedReader would be faster than Scanner though :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Yeah, `Scanner` is a beast, performance-wise. For simple line reading, `BufferedReader` is the way to go.

Comment: @Andreas: I went with your BufferedReader suggestion and solved it. :)

Comment: @Sugarcoder If one of the answers is the right answer for you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: @Andreas I did already, but it doesn't show until I have 15 reputation.

Comment: @Sugarcoder I thought that only applied to an "up-vote" (up-arrow), not to the "accept" (checkmark).

Comment: @Andreas Ah, sorry...still new on SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

`inputsArray[0]` will contain

> Lois Lane,         100, 98, 95, 90, 93, 88, 92
>
> Marie Calendar,    85,82, 88, 78, 85, 86, 90
>
> Bob Marley,        70, 75, 72, 78, 80, 82, 76

Thats why its not able to parse that string.

`Integer.parseInt()` takes only numbers in String format

Comment: It actually contains the entire text, not just the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You see your code

```
 for (int i = 0; i < inputsArray.length; i++) {
        parsedArray = Integer.parseInt(inputsArray[i]);   // This line throws the exception
    }
```

will throw an error since there are String values which cannot be converted to int.

Use this code

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class testAvg {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            int[] receivedArray = getArray();
            System.out.println("The received array is");
            for (int i : receivedArray) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

        public static int[] getArray() throws FileNotFoundException {
            String line;

            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    //        inFile.useDelimiter(",");

            ArrayList<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
                line = inFile.nextLine();//use nextLine to get the complete line
                String nums = line.substring(1 + line.indexOf(",")).replace(" ", "");//removing the name from each line
                String[] num = nums.split(",");//split the nums
                for (String number : num) {
                    inputs.add(Integer.parseInt(number));//Directly parsing the int values
                }
            }
            inFile.close();
            int[] passedArray = new int[inputs.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
                passedArray[i] = inputs.get(i);//converting to int
            }
            return passedArray;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why convert `inputs` to `inputsArray`? Just use `inputs.get(i)` in the loop. And why `new Integer[1]`, and not size `0` or `inputs.size()`? --- Using catch exception to ignore parse errors is ... discouraged.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't change the whole source code. Just made a quick review   and change the error lines.

Comment: Thank you and @Andreas for the suggestions! I truly appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Sugarcoder you can now use the modified code if you want.

Comment: @shivam7357: the last column of numbers was not parsed for some reason. It was left out of the result. :/

Comment: @Sugarcoder oh yes, now I have corrected the mistake and posted the new code.